# Wildfly - "Connector 'netty' not found on the main configuration file"

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, netty, wildfly

I've added a connection factory at the `standalone-full` file of Wildfly:

```
<jms-connection-factories>
    <connection-factory name="K19Factory">
        <connectors>
            <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
        </connectors>
        <entries>
            <entry name="K19Factory"/>
            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/K19Factory"/>
        </entries>
    </connection-factory>
    ...
</jms-connection-factories>
```

And I have the following code to use it:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();

 props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

 props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080/"); 

 /*props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url","remote://localhost:8080");*/

 props.setProperty("java.naming.security.principal","k19");

 props.setProperty("java.naming.security.credentials","1234");

 InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);

 // factory of JMS connections
 ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("jms/K19Factory");
```

But I'm facing problems. Widfly is saying it can't find the `Netty` connector, so it can't create the connection factory.

```
...
17:07:02,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name queue/pedidos
17:07:02,331 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.topic.noticias
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name topic/noticias
17:07:02,331 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: JBAS011639: Failed to create connection-factory
    at org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.ConnectionFactoryService$1.run(ConnectionFactoryService.java:69) [wildfly-messaging-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: HornetQIllegalStateException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=HQ129005: Connector 'netty' not found on the main configuration file]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.internalCreateCFPOJO(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1421) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.internalCreateCF(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1368) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.access$1300(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:107) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl$5.runException(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1215) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.runAfterActive(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1906) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.createConnectionFactory(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:1201) [hornetq-jms-server-2.4.5.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.ConnectionFactoryService$1.run(ConnectionFactoryService.java:66) [wildfly-messaging-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 4 more

17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/noticias
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/jms/queue/DLQ
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue
17:07:02,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
17:07:02,472 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
17:07:02,488 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.2.Final
17:07:02,545 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-8) HornetQ resource adaptor started
17:07:02,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-8) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
17:07:02,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
17:07:02,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
17:07:02,545 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "messaging"),
    ("hornetq-server" => "default"),
    ("connection-factory" => "K19Factory")
]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: JBAS011639: Failed to create connection-factory
    Caused by: HornetQIllegalStateException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=HQ129005: Connector 'netty' not found on the main configuration file]"}}
17:07:02,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.K19Factory: JBAS011639: Failed to create connection-factory
```

Can someone give me a hand on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is due the fact that you are referencing a non-existent connector. By default does not exist a `netty-connector`, but other such as `http-connector`.

'Cause you're using `standalone-full`, I'll consider that `org.jboss.as.messaging` module is enabled.

First, we have to include an `acceptor`, responsible by accepting connections that will be made to the server. For this, in the messaging subsystem (XML namespace `urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0`) find `acceptors`tag and add this:

```xml
<netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging" />
<netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
</netty-acceptor>
```

After this, we have to include a `connector`, responsible by transport configurations (how to connect) on the server. For this, in the messaging subsystem (XML namespace `urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0`) find `connectors`tag and add this:

```xml
<netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging" />
<netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
</netty-connector>
```

Finally you have to configure the *socket binding*. Find `socket-binding-group` tag and include this:

```xml
<socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
<socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
```

See also the documentation of [JBoss EAP](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-Messaging.html) (Obs.: there are differences in the EAP settings for Wildfly/AS Community, especially directories, but overall it is a good reference) and of [Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-Messaging) for more detailed configuration of messaging system.

Given this setting and your `connection-factory`, this code should works:

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user"); // add an application user before
props.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "user1234");

final InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);

final ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/K19Factory");
System.out.println(factory != null ? "Factory is not null" : "Factory is null");
```

This is the log of *lookup* (source above):

```
Jun 02, 2015 7:18:13 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
Jun 02, 2015 7:18:13 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
Jun 02, 2015 7:18:13 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
Factory is not null
```

And this is the log in WildFly:

```
19:18:13,731 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (default task-35) JBAS011806: Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 24a74dfb (inbound) of Remoting connection 29a8f328 to /127.0.0.1:63595
```

To run this example you may need these dependencies in yout classpath:

- [`jboss-remote-naming`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jboss-remote-naming/2.0.4.Final)
- [`hornetq-jms-client`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hornetq/hornetq-jms-client/2.4.7.Final)
- a *XNIO provider*, like [`xnio-nio`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.xnio/xnio-nio/3.3.1.Final)

Comment: Its worth pointing out that even though you've added a netty connector, your client is still connecting over http to the server.  You now have unnecessary configuration on your server.

Answer (score 0):

WildFly leverages Servlet's protocol upgrade feature to drive all traffic over http/https.  You should see by default some connectors in your xml like this

```
            <connectors>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http">
                    <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/>
                </http-connector>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                    <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor-throughput"/>
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>
```

With these, you get a http connector and in-vm connector.  Based on the contents [here](http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/subsystem/messaging/hornetq-server/index.html) I don't see a netty connector available.  You should ideally stick with the http and in-vm connectors, for performance reasons.